# Why is my datapicker onSelect event firing as soon as the popup loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I created a datepicker that is loaded in a partial view.  The partial view itself is loaded in a popup dialog. Not sure that’s relevant but when the dialog box pops up, the date picker is already open.  It seems that onSelect event fires by default when the datepicker loads.

I have the date picker in a div like this:

```
 <div class ="ui-widget" >
      <label for ="datep">Date: </label><input id="datep" />
  </div>
```

And here’s the script:
      $(function () {

```
        $("#datep").datepicker({ showOn: "both", buttonText: "Select Date", changeMonth: true, showButtonBar: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "-2:+2", showOtherMonths: true, onSelect: function (date, datepickder) {
            var tcherData = { selectedDate: date, teacherID: teacherData };
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Schedule/GetSchedule",
                data: tcherData,
                datatype: "html",
                sucess: function (data) {

                }
            });
        }
     });
```

Why is the onSelect event firing as soon as the popup loads?  How can I prevent this from happening?  Thanks for any help with this one!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the dialog is opened then the focus is set on the input which triggers the datepicker. The solution is to either you trigger the blur event on input when dialog is shown or you can use this code before you call the dialog, it will clear autofocus :

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._focusTabbable = function(){};
```